# How can I read from a text file in R?

Tags: r, text

How can I read from a text file? I have the following data in a text file-

 A,B,C,D 
  E,F,G,H

Iam trying to choose the file interactively.

`read.delim(file.choose(), sep=",")`

`Warning messages:
    1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls<br>
    2: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,

    :
  line 2 appears to contain embedded nulls<br>
    3: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,

  :
      line 3 appears to contain embedded nulls<br>
    4: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,

    :
  line 4 appears to contain embedded nulls<br>
    5: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,

    :
      line 5 appears to contain embedded nulls<br>
    6: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,

     :
      EOF within quoted string<br>
    7: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,

    :
  embedded nul(s) found in input`

I wish to simply read the data and store it in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `read.csv`:

```
your_df <- read.csv(file="/path/to/your_file.csv", header=FALSE)
your_df

  v1 v2 v3 v4
1  A  B  C  D
2  E  F  G  H
```

The `header` parameter to `read.csv` tells R that your input CSV file does not have a leading header row with column names.

Answer (score 0):

Install and attach `data.table` then use `fread`

```
fread(file.choose(), sep = ",")
```

Your error could be due to encoding issues - specify the right encoding:

```
fread(file.choose(), sep = ",", encoding = "INSERT YOUR ENCODING"`)
```